# Android : Grid-view item delete or remove

Tags: android

I'm trying to delete GridView item from sdcard folder if exist that selected image path and from adapter also.But in my code neither delete from sdcard folder and adapter.Here is my code.I don't understand where I'm wrong.

```
     File gridFilePath ;
        HashSet<String> selectedFile = new HashSet<String>();
        ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] listFile;
        public void getFromSdcard()
        {
            String strFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "classnkk_images";


 File file = new File(strFilePath);

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }
    }


 imgDeleteImagesFromGallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgDeleteImage);
        imgDeleteImagesFromGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Iterator iterator = selectedFile.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    gridFilePath = new File(iterator.next().toString());
                    if(gridFilePath.exists())
                    {
                        gridFilePath.delete();
                       // gridAdapter.remove(position);
                        gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my GridAdapter class

```
 class GridView_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<BitmapItems>

    {

        private Context context;
        private int layoutResourceId;
        private ArrayList<BitmapItems> data = new ArrayList<BitmapItems>();

        public GridView_Adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<BitmapItems> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return 0;
        return data.size();
    }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

         BitmapItems item = data.get(position);
        //holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getBitmap());
            final int pos = position;
            Log.e("pos "," = " + pos);

            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   if(!selectedFile.contains((String)f.get(pos)))
                    {
                        selectedFile.add((String) f.get(pos));
                        String path = ((String) f.get(pos));
                        selectedFile.add(path);
                        Log.e("path "," = " + path);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        selectedFile.remove((String)f.get(pos));
                        String path = ((String) f.get(pos));
                        selectedFile.add(path);
                        Log.e("path ", " = " + path);
                    }
                }
            });

        return row;
    }

         class ViewHolder {
            //  TextView imageTitle;
             ImageView image;
             CheckBox checkbox;
             int id;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: when your call notifyDatasetChanged, does the variable data of Adapter not change?

Comment: Yes actually , does not delete images from gridview .

Comment: I means you do not change the ```data``` in your Adapter, so the images are not delete from gridview.

Comment: Yes my adapter is not change .